# C# MySQL use transactions in a loop safely in same connection

Tags: c#, mysql, mysql-connector

Having opened a connection I want to do a transaction multiple times, I don't want to open the connection again and again because this would greatly hinder performance. With the below code I get an exception the second time in the loop of `Transaction has already been committed or is not pending`.

My question is - what do I need to add to the end of the loop/ beginning of the code to keep using transactions on the same MySql connection?

The code:

```
    using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(hostString))
    {
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            conn.ChangeDatabase(databaseName);

            /// put in db using a transaction
            MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            MySqlTransaction trans;
            trans = conn.BeginTransaction();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.Transaction = trans;

            while (someStuff)
            {
                try
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = getPersonUpdateString();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    cmd.CommandText = getBookUpdateString();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    trans.Commit();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    writeError("", ex);
                    try
                    {
                       trans.Rollback();
                    }
                    catch (MySqlException)
                    {
                       writeError("", ex);
                    }
                }
            }
         }
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you commit the transaction, you have to start another one. This means you need to move the `BeginTransaction` method call into the loop, like so.

```
        while (someStuff)            
        {
            MySqlTransaction trans;
            try
            {
                trans = conn.BeginTransaction();

                cmd.CommandText = getPersonUpdateString();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                cmd.CommandText = getBookUpdateString();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                trans.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                writeError("", ex);
                try
                {
                   trans.Rollback();
                }
                catch (MySqlException)
                {
                   writeError("", ex);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I think that  **trans = conn.BeginTransaction();** should be put outside of the try, otherwise is not defined in the body of the **catch**, probably we need two layers of try/catch because **BeginTranslation** can also fail.